# MS SQL JDBC - SQLServerCallableStatement - execute() returns false

Tags: java, jdbc

I have written code which should call MSSQL 2005 procedure from my servlet. The problem is the procedure is to SELECT data from table so I want to get ResultSet but the result set is never returns :( I tested the procedure with another procedure and it works, moreover, the client connection privileges are dbowner so there should be no problem with connection but still the execute returns false :(

Here is the problem code (current connection is connected I checked):

```
...
    SQLServerCallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    callableStatement = (SQLServerCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(
                        "{call "+
                        DATABASE_NAME+
                        "."+
                        SCHEMA_NAME+
                        ".select_item_proc(?,?,?)}");

                        callableStatement.setInt(1, 0);
                callableStatement.setString(2, "value1");
                callableStatement.setString(3, "value2");

           boolean rs=callableStatement.execute();

          if(rs)
          {
             ResultSet result=callableStatement.getResultSet();




                while (result.next()) {

                    String col1= result.getString(1);
                    String col2=result.getString(2);
                    System.out.print(col1+",");
                    System.out.println(col2);


                }


}
...
```

So I need your fresh sight what the problem really can be? Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using `ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();` instead of the `boolean rs=callableStatement.execute();` line.

Comment: Thanks... Actually the problem was also in params values but executeQuery() helped me